# Look up value in a cell exists as substring in range of cells

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of names I need to check against our registry. Vlookup function only works where full name on my list matches exactly name in registry. For example, "John Roger Smith" only matches if the registry contains the account name "John Roger Smith".

If I break up (text to column) names - for example, `A1: John`, `B1: Roger`, `C1: Smith` - how can I check if the name *John* is contained in the registry as a substring? (Registry displayed as `1 column` with full account name)?

Comment: something like contains ? , can you show the figure of what your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly...

```
    =ISNUMBER(SEARCH(substring,text))

    =ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,YourRegistryColumHere))
```

https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text